# Воспроизведение фонового видео на сайте с Google Drive или Яндекс Диска автоматически после загрузки страницы

Tags: css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, видео, веб-дизайн

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как воспроизводить фоновое видео на сайте Google Drive или Яндекс Диска автоматически после загрузки страницы, и в круговую, без панели управления.Понимание атрибутов autopley и loop - есть, но для Google Drive и Яндекс Диска они почему то не актуальны.

По умолчанию видео не воспроизводится и предлагается кнопка Play.

Answer (score 1):

```
<video controls autoplay>
   <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xz8cPqYe-Ek" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Нужно просто добавить атрибут `autoplay` . Но учтите, что не все браузеры поддерживают видеопроигрывание

Comment: Владислав добрый день. autoplay, loop  и т.д., там по моему не так всё просто, я конечно - попробую. Через час - доложу.) Спасибо.

Comment: @DariaShvakh у меня недавно была верстка с видео, и видео должно воспроизводится сразу, так вот autoplay?=1 - для ютуба, а так нужен всего лишь атрибут autoplay.

Comment: Vladyslav Tereshyn <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xz8cPqYe-Ek" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay?=1; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe> - не запускает видео.

Comment: так при чем здесь iframe? мы ж говорили о <video></video>

Comment: где у вас http://.....

Comment: iframe это тег для встраивания видео, но сейчас попробую по ссылке через video

Comment: нет и <video width="1280" autoplay?=1 loop><source src="https://youtu.be/xz8cPqYe-Ek"></video>---не идёт(

Comment: @DariaShvakh у вас даже источника видео нет, его не существует

Comment: источника видео, это как выглядит ? можно пример! это не src="youtu.be/xz8cPqYe-Ek"

Comment: так вы перейдите по этой ссылке и поймете о чем я говорю

Comment: <video width="1280" autoplay?=1 loop><source src="https://youtu.be/xz8cPqYe-Ek"></video>

Comment: странно копирую с https://--> Вставляю --> Сохраняю и результат на экране. Если ссылку выделить и правой кнопкой мауса перейти то переходим.

Comment: @DariaShvakh я дополнил ответ iframe'om с вашим видео

Comment: если этот фрейм через js-сниппет вставить, то что-то черный прямоугольник и все

Comment: @teran я на компьютере у себя пробовал, не знаю что там в сниппете

Comment: Vladyslav Tereshyn, ну да он фрейм в страницу- вставляет, но не воспроизводит автоматически(....teran-спасибо.